# How can I increment a label by pressing a button that is in a separate view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

so basically I'm familiar with app development and Xcode, but I'm still in the beginning stages of learning and I need some help. I've created a emotions quiz type UI and at the end of the 10 questions, I have a page that displays the different emotions and the scores that the user earned throughout the quiz. What I need help on is wen the user clicks a button on question 1 to get the label on my results page to increase by 1. I've tried many different methods so far but can't seem to quite figure it out. Ive linked my buttons to their respective view controller as actions and the labels to their respective view controller as outlets.

```
    import UIKit

class Question1: UIViewController {

@IBAction func buttonlightgreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print ("light green")
    sadscoreText += 1

}

@IBAction func buttonred(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("red")
    angryscoreText += 2
    happyscoreText += 1
}

@IBAction func buttonpurple(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("purple")
    annoyedscoreText += 1
    stressedscoreText += 1
}

@IBAction func buttondarkgreen(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("dark green")
    relaxedscoreText += 2
    tiredscoreText += 1
}

@IBAction func buttonyellow(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("yellow")
    happyscoreText += 1
}



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}



}
```

That is the code for the buttons and this is the code for the labels.

```
    import UIKit

var sadscoreText = 0
var happyscoreText = 0
var relaxedscoreText = 0
var angryscoreText = 0
var annoyedscoreText = 0
var tiredscoreText = 0
var stressedscoreText = 0

class Results: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sadscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var happyscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var relaxedscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var angryscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var annoyedscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tiredscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stressedscore: UILabel!


var sadscoreText: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        sadscore.text = "\(sadscoreText)"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sadscoreText = 0
    happyscoreText = 0
    relaxedscoreText = 0
    angryscoreText = 0
    annoyedscoreText = 0
    tiredscoreText = 0
    stressedscoreText = 0
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason its not working is because you are assigning 0 to the values before assigning the modified values to label in viewDidLoad method. You can achieve the required behaviour like this:

Modify your Results view controller as follows:

```
import UIKit

var sadscoreText = 0
var happyscoreText = 0
var relaxedscoreText = 0
var angryscoreText = 0
var annoyedscoreText = 0
var tiredscoreText = 0
var stressedscoreText = 0

class Results: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sadscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var happyscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var relaxedscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var angryscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var annoyedscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tiredscore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stressedscore: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sadscore.text = "\(sadscoreText)"
    happyscore.text = "\(happyscoreText)"
//follow the same for other labels

//you can set the values again to zero after showing the labels on the screen like this
    sadscoreText = 0
    happyscoreText = 0

}
}
```